# Launchd based daemon exit with abnormal code 1, without crash log

Tags: macos, launchd, plist, daemons

I've seen many questions that relate to specific daemons/applications that exit on this same exit code (=1). All scenarios seems unique and unconnected.

I created a daemon of my own, and also got the same sudden exit with exit code 1. If i could't only realize the meaning of this error code...

unfortunately, there's no crash log with backtraces i can look into, so i deduce it's a planned process termination... 
is there any documentation which describe abnormal code per index ?

perhaps it's  connected with my plist. I've added 2 keys that might be relevant : KeepAlive and RunAtLoad.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've just realize that i left `exit(1)` in my code. this was part of non deamon leftovers, and that what caused the abnormal exit.